# How to I split a string to retrieve the ids in a list?

Tags: apex, string

> I tried to retreive the ids that I got from the String 'currentpageid' which are separated by the '$' operator.But it is faililing to do so .Please suggest me a way to retreive the ids separated by $ symbol

```
    currentPageId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rids');   
    system.debug('currentPageId::'+currentPageId);

    String[] ids=currentPageId.split('\\$');
    system.debug(ids);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the string you are getting looks like `id1$id2$id3`, then you are using the correct syntax. I just ran the below in execute anonymous and got a size of 3.

```
String str = 'id1$id2$id3';
List<String> arr = str.split('\\$');
System.debug(arr.size());
```

If it isn't working, what does your code output in the debug?

Comment: Yes Daniel it is working right now .Thank you for the answer .Earlier I was doing a mistake of adding an extra '\' charecter .That's why the error